# How do I stop my objects from going through walls when I pick them up and drop them down?

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I pick an object up I can glitch it through the map making it fall out of the world. This happens when I pick it up and drop the object half way through the floor. The outcome I receive is not what I was expecting what can I do to fix this. Also yes the colliders and rigidbody's are setup correctly.

```
public GameObject PressEtoInteractText;

public bool pickup, inrange;

public Collider Playercol;

public Vector3 guide;

private GameObject temp;

private Rigidbody rb;

void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && inrange == true)
    {
        PressEtoInteractText.SetActive(false);
        pickup = true;
    }

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && pickup == true)
    {
        pickup = false;
        Playercol.isTrigger = true;
    }
    UpdatePickUpFollow();
}

void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Interact")
    {
        PressEtoInteractText.SetActive(true);
        temp = other.gameObject;
        inrange = true;
    }

    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Interact" && temp.transform.position == guide)
    {
        return;
    }
}

void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.name != "Interact")
    {
        PressEtoInteractText.SetActive(false);
        inrange = false;
    }
}

public void PickUp()
{
    rb = temp.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    rb.MovePosition(transform.position += guide);
    Playercol.isTrigger = false;
}

public void UpdatePickUpFollow()
{
    if (pickup == true)
    {
        PickUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you deactivate the objects collider with `tempCol.enabled = false;` it will **not register any collisions** and you can just push or pull it through walls all day. Make sure to remove that from your script.

Also, using `MoveTowards` can cause issues with collision detection. In my experience it is best to use `AddForce` or `MovePosition` to move the Rigidbody component instead of modifying the Transform directly. Try `Rigidbody.MovePosition(Vector3 position)`. Maybe this works better for you.

Here is a link to the documentation page. It's basically your exact use case:

[Rigidbody.MoveTowards Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html)

(Hint: notice how they use `FixedUpdate` instead of regular `Update`. You should also always do this when working with Rigidbodies because it is synced with physics updates.)

//Edit:
This is a little implementation of your code in a cleaner and hopefully correct way. I have **not tested this** and there is propably something I missed. Use this as a reference to build your own working solution.

```
    //set in inspector
public Transform guidePosition;
public GameObject pressEToInteractText;

private bool isObjectInRange;
private GameObject inRangeObject;
private bool isObjectPickedUp;
private Rigidbody pickedUpRigidBody;

/*  check if button is pressed. 
 *  If no object is in hand -> pick up; 
 *  if object is in hand -> drop;
 */ 
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && isObjectInRange && !isObjectPickedUp)
    {
        PickupObject();
    }

    if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && isObjectPickedUp)
    {
        DropObject();
    }

    if (isObjectPickedUp)
    {
        PickedUpObjectFollow();
    }
}

//save references 
private void PickupObject()
{
    pickedUpRigidBody = inRangeObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    isObjectPickedUp = true;
}

//remove saved references
private void DropObject()
{
    isObjectPickedUp = false;
    pickedUpRigidBody = null;
}

//move position to guidePosition
private void PickedUpObjectFollow()
{
    pickedUpRigidBody.MovePosition(guidePosition.position);
}

private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Interact") && !isObjectPickedUp)
    {
        pressEToInteractText.SetActive(true);
        isObjectInRange = true;
        inRangeObject = other.gameObject;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Interact") && other.gameObject == inRangeObject)
    {
        pressEToInteractText.SetActive(false);
        isObjectInRange = false;
        inRangeObject = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I remove it and used move position but with no result. I update my cod above.

Comment: I assume your `Vector3 guide` is the position this object should follow? 
`rb.MovePosition(transform.position += guide);` does not work like that. Use it like this `rb.MovePosition(guide);` and update your guide position externally. I am going to edit my answer with a little example that works on my end.

Answer (score 0):

You could do multiple things. Unfortunately the way VR tracks the hands and there is no way to stop ur hands in real life your hand will defy the physics in the application.

I would either make the item drop from the users hand when it gets close enough to a certain area that you dont want it going through.

Or you can make it that if it does pass through a space you can report the item right above the floor it went through.

Ive looked long and hard for an answer to this and it doesnt seem like it can at this point be blocked from moving through if its currently grabbed.